# how do I apply a prototype to an existing object

Tags: javascript, prototype, typescript

I have a REST API which returns a JSON array of objects (contacts).

In my app I have a Contact class which defines the usual properties and a bunch of methods (eg. `hasAPhoneNumber()=>boolean`).

How do I promote each of the REST objects to be instances of my Contact class, other than by transcribing the properties into a new Contact object?

I'm using TypeScript in case there is a TS-specific approach, or plain old JS will also be OK.

So, I want to be able to do this...

> ```
> // fetch the contacts 
> var contactsArray = fetchContactsFromRestApi();
>
> // do something to each contact so it becomes an instance of Contact
> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> // use the newly applied method(s)
> if (contactsArray[2].hasAPhoneNumber() == false) {    
>    alert("sorry you can't call "+contactsArray[2].name+
>           " because he/she has no phone number");
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 3):

You already have array of JSON objects, which should have the "Contact" as prototype.
So, first create an object of Contact.

```
var cont = new Contact(); //the prototype object
```

Now add it as prototype to each object.

```
//if contacts is the JSON array
contacts.forEach(function(jsonObj){
  jsonObj.__proto__ = cont;
  jsonObj.constructor = Contact;
});
```

Now, each of the object of your json array will have the same Contact prototype.
This is not the smart way of adding prototype, but you said you do not want to instantiate those JSON objects again. Hence this would serve the purpose.

Comment: `__proto__` is deprecated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: @thefourtheye: there isn't really any other option (currently) if you want to change the prototype of an object to a completely different object after creation.

Comment: Yes. __proto__ is deprecated. But, according to requirement, this is the possible solution. the OP doesn't want to create any new objects for this (really dunno why so!!)

Comment: I'm looking for a best practice answer, so if the way I phrased the question, there is no recommended solution, so be it. My reason for phrasing the question as I have is that the REST array is being returned by AngularJS' $resource, and is bound to my UI. If I transcribe the results to a new array, I lose some of the elegance of the inbuilt databinding.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no elegant way to do this. I don't want to use a deprecated property (**proto**), and the newer ES6 alternative is also disapproved of.

The approach I'll take instead is to simply have a static ContactsMethods class with methods such as my hasAPhoneNumber()

So instead of

> contactsArray[2].hasAPhoneNumber()

I'll end up with

> ContactsMethods.hasAPhoneNumber(contactsArray[2])

imho less readable, but avoids (a) using non-recommended techniques, and (b) cloning an array.

I won't accept my own answer in the hope that there is a better approach, but it's here for completeness in case anybody has the same dilemna.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use [the `Object.setPrototypeOf` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) to do this.